# Why my question was closed?

Tags: discussion

Why my question was closed?

[Where in the world knowing Russian and English will not be enough?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14144/where-in-the-world-knowing-russian-and-english-will-not-be-enough)

Why similar questions about English are allowed?

[Can you really get around everywhere with only speaking English?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3054/can-you-really-get-around-everywhere-with-only-speaking-english)

Answer (score 5):

In this case, the question was closed by a community vote and not by the moderators. The reason why I think the community closed this question is because yours essentially asks for a list of countries which could be hard to quantify, while the other one is a) an old question when the community was still developing, so perhaps it slid through and maybe it was asked today would get closed b) is essentially asking a yes/no question with supporting arguments on whether English is enough, so the scope is a tad more focussed.